# Removing matlab objects from arrays, deleting empty array spaces

Tags: oop, matlab

For this example object :

```
    classdef TestObject < handle
    %UNTITLED Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        a;
    end

    methods
    end

end
```

and this example script:

```
 tbarray = TestObject.empty();

for i=1:3
    newTestObject=TestObject;
    newTestObject.a=i;
    if(i==1)
        firstTestObject=newTestObject;
    end
    tbarray(end+1,1)=newTestObject;
end
delete (firstTestObject) ;
```

After this is run tbarray first position has an empty TestObject.  Is it possible to either resize tbarray, removing empty objects, or use some sort of remove call e.g.

```
index=tbarray.remove(firstObject);
tbarray.add(index,laterTestObject);
```

or `tbarray.Replace(firstObject,laterObject);`

**Update:**
How would I find the array index of the object I want to remove/replace.  This example uses 1, but it may be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tbarray(1) = []` will remove the index 1 and resize the array (so it has now 1 less length).
`tbarray(1) = laterObject` will replace at index 1.

There is no Set or Map with keys of any class (and not just primitives/strings) in Matlab, so things like `tbarray.Replace(firstObject,laterObject);` are near to impossible to implement without knowing the index.

---

**Edit**
If you want to find indices of occurrences of some element in the array, you may use `find(tbarray == firstObject)`.
Note that `tbarray == firstObject` returns a logical array which can be used directly as index, e.g. `tbarray(tbarray == firstObject) = []` or `tbarray(tbarray == firstObject) = laterObject`.

However, you should remember that these operations are expensive, as the whole array is traversed. If you can define some unique key of type `double`, `single`, array of `char`, or signed or unsigned 32-bit or 64-bit integers for your objects, you may store them in `containers.Map`.

In this example you use a handle class. If you need a value class, you will also need to define a vectorized eq() method on it.

Comment: thanks!!! this worked for this code example where I know the index of objectToRemove.  But in my case how do I search for an object in the list, get its index, then remove/replace at that index.